# Регулярное выражение для извлечения url из значения свойства css

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

str принимает значения 'url(/*ссылка*/)' и 'url("/*ссылка*/")'.
Извлекаю ссылку регулярными выражениями:

```
url = url.replace(/(^url[(]"?)/, '').replace(/"?[)]$/, '')
```

Каким образом объединить эти два регулярных выражения в одно? (или преобразовать в более эффективное)

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
var str = 'background: url(http://example.com/img/bg.jpg) no-repeat;';
    str = str.replace(/^(.*?)\((.*?)\)(.*?)+$/gi, "$2");
    alert(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Тоже занекропосчу, мне кажется эффективнее будет избежать двойного сканирования:

```js
var tests = [
  'url(image1.png)',
  'url("image2.png")'
];
tests.forEach(function(test) {
  console.log(test.replace(/^url\("?(.*?)"?\)$/, "$1"));
});
```

Comment: к сожалению это менее эффективно, чем мой вариант. Вы можете немного ускорить Ваше регулярное выражение убрав знак минимальной квантификации оставив «жадную» квантификацию, но это медленнее двух очень быстрых поисков, привязанных к якорным символам начала и конца строки.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/regexp-or-vs-one в разных браузерах по-разному

Comment: спасибо за бенчмарк. Добавил еще одну ревизию, которая напрочь рвет регулярное выражение с альтернативой. По крайней мере в моем браузере. Нужно просто убрать минимальную квантификацию.

Comment: я забыл вам сказать - жадный квантификатор не работает, я же `?` туда не случайно вставил, http://jsfiddle.net/bxnspvqx/

Comment: виноват. Добавил пятую ревизию. Ну теперь то уж точно наверно самое производительное :) `test.replace( /^url\(("|)(.*)\1\)$/, "$2" )` . Неистово плюсую Ваш ответ. К сожалению мой вариант теоретически должен работать быстрее. Практика к сожалению показывает слабую оптимизацию регулярных выражений движками.

Answer (score 0):

Просто объединить два выражения альтернативой:

```
url = url.replace( /^url\("?|"?\)$/g , '' )
```

Эффективнее для данной задачи ничего быть не может.